# How to get a ever changing value from a website using Selenium

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium

I wanna read a sites value, the value i wanna read is "DKK 5.000,00" here is the sample size from the website

```
<span class="text"> Saldo : </span>
<span class="text value"> DKK 5.000,00 </span>
<span class ="text" > < / span >
```

Here is my code that doesn't work

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
PATH = r"c:\Users\test\Desktop\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.royalcasino.dk/spilleautomater/spil-for-sjov/european-roulette")


sleep(10)

saldo = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*")
for i in saldo:
    print(i.text)

print(saldo.text)

exit()
```

the value I want to receive changes alot

when i'm running the program it outputs, all text on the site, but only the static text, is this cause the dynamic text can't be read from selenium ?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is generally difficult to parse as a problem. Please describe what you expected to happen and what is happening instead.

Comment: I want the code to output "Small" 

it doesnt output that, it says :
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".text value"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem like you element target having more than one class name `text` and `value`:

```
<span class="text value"> Small </span>
```

**`.find_element_by_class_name`** just for single class name.

Instead use **`.find_element_by_css_selector`**:

```
saldo = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.text.value')
print(saldo.text)
```

**#UPDATE**

To get text `DKK 5.000,00` you mean, you can use this xpath:

```
//span[contains(text(), "Saldo")]//following-sibling::span[@class="text value" and text()!=""]
```

But you have `<iframe>` nested in the page, you need switch it first. And use `WebDriverWait` instead of `sleep(...)`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

PATH = r"c:\Users\test\Desktop\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get('https://www.royalcasino.dk/spilleautomater/spil-for-sjov/european-roulette')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, 'GameflexWidget-1')))
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, 'GameObjectContainer')))
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//span[contains(text(), "Saldo")]//following-sibling::span[@class="text value" and text()!=""]')))
print(element.text)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Hi i was wondering, since 
<span class="text"> Size: </span>
<span class="text value"> Small </span>
<span class ="text" > < / span >
Is inside a Div called "Wrapper" which is inside a <span class="inline field credit"> 
and so on and so on... is that the reason i cant find it, when im using your metode. btw im sorry i didnt give all in info, didnt think that the 10 divs/span where important, and maybe they aren't, but thanks for your reply

Comment: hi i updated the question, got any solutions ? :) thanks for the first answer tho :)